# Defining a function comprising other defined functions

Tags: function-construction

In the finite element method, $x$-$y$ space is represented in terms of an isoparametric $\xi$-$\eta$ space using shape functions $N_{i}$ as interpolants of nodal coordinates $(x_{i},y_{i})$, where

$x=\sum_{i=1}^{n}N_{i}x_{i}$

and in this case $n=5$.

I am trying to create $x$ as a function of $\xi$ and $\eta$ and display the function as well as a simplified version of the function. See the code below.

```
(* Interpolants *)
N1[ξ_, η_] := -1/4 ξ (1 - ξ) (1 - η);
N2[ξ_, η_] := 1/2 (1 - ξ) (1 + ξ) (1 - η);
N3[ξ_, η_] := 1/4 ξ (1 + ξ) (1 - η);
N4[ξ_, η_] := 1/4 (1 + ξ) (1 + η);
N5[ξ_, η_] := 1/4 (1 - ξ) (1 + η);
(* Nodal Positions *)
X1 = 0; Y1 = 0;
X2 = 1/2; Y2 = 1/8;
X3 = 1; Y3 = 1/2;
X4 = 1; Y4 = 1;
X5 = 0; Y5 = 1;
x[ξ_, η_] := N1 X1 + N2 X2 + N3 X3 + N4 X4 + N5 X5;
Print[x[ξ, η]];
Print[Simplify[x[ξ, η]]];
```

Which produces the output

```
N2 / 2 + N3 + N4
N2 / 2 + N3 + N4
```

which is not in terms of $\xi$ and $\eta$. Once this is working I would also like to print out $y(\xi,\eta)$ which is calculated in a similar manner.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think  the problem is how you called your `N`, you need to pass them the arguments as well. Like this

```
x[ξ_, η_] := N1[ξ, η] X1 + N2[ξ, η] X2 + N3[ξ, η] X3 +    N4[ξ, η] X4 + N5[ξ, η] X5;
```

And now

```
x[ξ, η]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And simplifying the above gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Because you defined your $N_i$ as functions `N1[ξ_, η_]` so you need to also call them the same way you defined them.

To do what you had before, then your code should have been like this

```
N1 = -1/4 ξ (1 - ξ) (1 - η);
N2 = 1/2 (1 - ξ) (1 + ξ) (1 - η);
N3 = 1/4 ξ (1 + ξ) (1 - η);
N4 = 1/4 (1 + ξ) (1 + η);
N5 = 1/4 (1 - ξ) (1 + η);
(*Nodal Positions*)
X1  = 0; Y1 = 0;
X2 = 1/2; Y2 = 1/8;
X3 = 1; Y3 = 1/2;
X4 = 1; Y4 = 1;
X5 = 0; Y5 = 1;
x = N1 X1 + N2 X2 + N3 X3 + N4 X4 + N5 X5;
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5):

For your consideration:

```
Attributes[passdown] = {HoldFirst};

passdown[LHS : _[par : __Pattern] := RHS_] := 
 SetDelayed @@ 
  Join[Hold[LHS], 
   Hold[par][[All, 1]] /. _[p__] :> 
     Replace[Hold[RHS], s_Symbol /; DownValues[s] =!= {} :> s[p], ∞]]
```

Usage:

```
passdown[
 x[ξ_, η_] := N1 X1 + N2 X2 + N3 X3 + N4 X4 + N5 X5
]
```

The definition created:

```
?x
```

> ```
> Global`x
>
> x[ξ_, η_] := N1[ξ, η] X1 + N2[ξ, η] X2 + N3[ξ, η] X3 + N4[ξ, η] X4 + N5[ξ, η] X5
> ```

```
x[a, b]
% // Simplify
```

> ```
> 1/4 (1 - a) (1 + a) (1 - b) + 1/4 a (1 + a) (1 - b) + 1/4 (1 + a) (1 + b)
>
> (1 + a)/2
> ```